# How to log in to SE sites using a second account

Tags: support, login, openid, winter-bash-2013, multiple-accounts

I created two SE accounts (the second was by mistake since I forgot my username), and now when I try to log in to [winterbash2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) site, it automatically logs me in using my second account instead of my primary one... How can I fix this, please?

If you can also tell me how to delete my second account, it would be even better.

Comment: You won't be able to delete the other account if you can't *log* into it. You should try & *recover* the account.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: I can log into both accounts, I just want to remove the empty one since it makes me problems and it's unused anyway...

Comment: If you only want to delete your account, you should take a look at [How can I delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)
Also, in this case, I would point that this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page (in your case the second paragraph):

https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

> If you can't remember how to log into one of your accounts, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address you used to create it.

Comment: I don't want to merge them since the other account is an empty one... deleting it would be great, unless it's impossible xD

Comment: @Enissay merging would effectively delete the empty one. It just means if you *had* made any questions on that account they would be merged into your proper account.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work.